# 'InvalidCastException' while trying to cast concrete object to generic interface

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a class using Activator.CreateInstance and cast it to a generic interface it implements.

Why am I getting 'InvalidCastException' at run time (.Net 4.0)?

Here is the code:

```
namespace CastingGenerics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var typeFromSomewhere = typeof(ActionSomethingValidator);

            // This line throw 'System.InvalidCastException'
            // "Unable to cast object of type 'CastingGenerics.ActionSomethingValidator' to type 'CastingGenerics.IActionValidator`1[CastingGenerics.IAction]'."
            var castingError = (IActionValidator<IAction>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFromSomewhere);
        }
    }

    internal interface IAction
    {
    }

    internal interface IActionValidator<in T>
        where T : IAction
    {
        bool Validate(T action, out string failure);
    }

    internal abstract class ActionValidator<T> : IActionValidator<T>
        where T : IAction
    {
        public abstract bool Validate(T action, out string failure);
    }

    internal class ActionSomethingValidator : ActionValidator<IActionSomething>
    {
        public override bool Validate(IActionSomething action, out string failure)
        {
            failure = string.Empty;
            return true;
        }
    }

    internal interface IActionSomething : IAction
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is an `IActionValidator<IActionSomething>`. `IActionValidator<IActionSomething>` cannot be assigned to `IActionValidator<IAction>`, because `T` is marked as an `in` type parameter.

Imagine, that for an `IActionValidator<IAction>` variable named `v`, there is the following `Validate` method:

```
Validate(IAction action, out string failure);
```

Now, if `v` pointed to an instance of `IActionValidator<IActionSomething>`, you could pass an `IAction` instance to the first parameter via `v` that does not implement `IActionSomething`. However, exactly the latter would be required for `IActionValidator<IActionSomething>`. Therefore, the compiler will not let you do this.

Comment: it still doesn't work even if i remove the `in` keyword from `IActionValidator<in T>`

Comment: @avivr: Of course; without the `in` keyword, neither of `IActionValidator<IAction>` and `IActionValidator<IActionSomething>` can be assigned to each other. With the `in`keyword, `IActionValidator<IAction>` can be assigned to `IActionValidator<IActionSomething>`, but not the other way round. That would be possible with the `out` keyword - but that in turn would contradict your declaration of `Validate`.

Comment: I agree with @O.R.Mapper . The cast fails because of the constraint on the ActionValidator<T> class. So the class ActionSomethingValidator can only be casted to IActionValidator<IActionSomething>.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic).

`dynamic smth = Activator.CreateInstance(typeFromSomewhere);`

You will lose the autocomplete feature since the editor cannot determine the type at design time. But you still able to invoke the methods just coding by hand.
`smth.Validate(() => true, "");`